# ID = None script doesn't return ID from List

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to Python. A script was made for parsing Flashscore via request. It takes data from the first page for all games for tomorrow.
`

```
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime


headers = {"x-fsign": "SW9D1eZo"}


def main():
    feed = 'f_1_1_1_en_1'
    url = f'https://d.flashscore.com/x/feed/{feed}'
    response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    data = response.text.split('¬')

    data_list = [{}]

    for item in data:
        key = item.split('÷')[0]
        value = item.split('÷')[-1]

        if '~' in key:
            data_list.append({key: value})
        else:
            data_list[-1].update({key: value})

    for game in data_list:
        if 'AA' in list(game.keys())[0]:
            id = game.get("AA")
            date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(game.get("AD")))
            team_1 = game.get("AE")
            team_2 = game.get("AF")
            score = f'{game.get("AG")} : {game.get("AH")}'

            print(id, date, team_1, team_2, score, sep=' ')

            #print(json.dumps(data_list, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
```

`

But then, I need to go into each game to get the H2H stats, get the average number of goals scored in the last 5 Home and Away games. And here I just can’t understand and do how I can pull out the ID of each game so that the page with H2H opens. On Selenium, I was able to do this, but nothing happens with request.

[image]

Please can you advise me and help me to do.
Thank you all in advance for your help and participation.

Comment: What is the description of the image you have linked to?

Comment: In the image, at the beginning of the line, it should output the ID of each match, but outputs None